# Sinon spy: Attempted to wrap undefined property 'path' as function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

The following spy on location.path is failing with an error:

> Attempted to wrap undefined property path as function
>
> ```
> it('should redirect location.path', function() {
>  sinon.spy(location, 'path');
>  scope.create();
>  expect(location.path).to.have.been.calledOnce;
>  location.path.restore();
> ```

**Mock Controller:**

```
describe('AdminUsersController', function() {
  var Users;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, $location, _Users_, _$httpBackend_) {
    var location;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    location = $location;
    controller = _$controller_('AdminUsersController', {
      $scope: scope,
      $location: location
    });
```

**Line that I'm trying to test:**

```
$scope.create = function() {
  return $location.path("admin/users/newuser?create");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was another silly coffeescript thing. I had not defined location previously. My code, in coffeescript, is as follows:

```
describe 'AdminControllers', () ->

  scope = undefined
  location = undefined
  $httpBackend = undefined

  beforeEach module 'heliotrope.controllers.admin'

  describe 'AdminUsersController', () ->

    beforeEach inject (_$controller_, $rootScope, $location, _Users_, _$httpBackend_) ->
      scope = $rootScope.$new()
      location = $location
      controller = _$controller_ 'AdminUsersController', {
        $scope: scope
        $location: location
      }
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_

    describe 'creating a new user', () ->

      it 'should redirect location.path', () ->
        sinon.spy(location, 'path')
        scope.create()
        expect(location.path).to.have.been.calledOnce
        location.path.restore()
```